# Distill and postcards: empty space above navbar

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

My distill website with a [postcards](https://github.com/seankross/postcards) homepage has an empty white space above the navbar that won't go away. Editing `theme.css` or `index.rmd` does not affect the white space. Other HTML pages look fine. Since the white space only impacts `index.html`, I'm assuming it has something to do with [postcards](https://github.com/seankross/postcards).

Also, `footer.html` doesn't appear on `index.html`, but the footer will appear on other HTML pages.

The white space only appears when I push the built website to Github. `index.html` looks fine when I view it locally.

```
---
title: "My Name"
image: images/me.jpg
links:
  - label: Twitter
    url: "https://twitter.com/myname"
  - label: GitHub
    url: "https://github.com/mygithubusername"
base_url: https://mygithubusername.github.io/
preview: images/me.jpg
site: distill::distill_website
output: postcards::trestles
---
```

```
name: "mygithubusername.github.io"
title: "My Name"
base_url: https://mygithubusername.github.io/
repository_url: https://github.com/mygithubusername/mygithubusername.github.io
twitter:
  site: "@myname"
description: |
  My Website
output_dir: "docs"
theme: theme.css 
navbar:
  right:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Resume"
      href: resume/resume.html
    - text: "Projects"
      menu:
        - text: "project1"
          href: https://github.com/mygithubusername/project1
        - text: "project2"
          href: https://github.com/mygithubusername/project2
        - text: "project3"
          href: project3.html
output: distill::distill_article
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling `distill` and `postcards` and adding this line to `theme.css`:

```
body { margin:0; padding: 0; }
```

Note: this does not solve the issue of the footer not appearing on `index.html`.